# Error creating FlinkKafkaConsumer in PyFlink: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-emr

Setup:

- aws emr cluster for flink
- aws msk for kafka

I'm trying to create a FlinkKafkaConsumer in PyFlink on aws emr cluster for reading data from Kafka topics, but I'm encountering an error during the creation of the FlinkKafkaConsumer. The error message I'm receiving is:

"**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError**: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer."

The code that I've used I mentioned below

```
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowDeserializationSchema

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
# the sql connector for kafka is used here as it's a fat jar and could avoid dependency issues
env.add_jars("file:///home/hadoop/flink-sql-connector-kafka.jar")

deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder() \    .type_info(type_info=Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])).build()

kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    topics='test_source_topic',    deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
    properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'xxxx:9096,xxxx:9096', 'group.id': 'python/mqtt'})

ds = env.add_source(kafka_consumer)
```